# Installation error for Google TV sdk

Tags: android-emulator, google-tv

I am using windows XP 32bit.
hardware spec-
64bit i3 quad core 3.4ghz.
It supports hardware acceleration.

It is showing google TV api level 13 add on is not installed. But while i try to download it, nothing is happening. Need help.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please revise your question. It is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Review the documents here:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

and

https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_addon

There is no Google TV SDK per say - it is am emulation library. Use android api level 13 to build applications. If you want to do Google TV specific feature coding like Channel Listings etc. have a look at the samples available here: 
https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_demo_samples